# Why does it say syntax error in line 61 (img = cv2.imread('Recources/shapesDif.png')? The image is the correct one

Tags: python, opencv

There is an invalid syntax error in line 61. I'm newish to openCV, and I have absolutely no clue why it says that. The majority of the code shouldn't be that imported for the question, but posted it just in case.
[**import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

```
def stackImages(scale,imgArray):
    rows = len(imgArray)
    cols = len(imgArray\[0\])
    rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray\[0\], list)
    width = imgArray\[0\]\[0\].shape\[1\]
    height = imgArray\[0\]\[0\].shape\[0\]
    if rowsAvailable:
        for x in range ( 0, rows):
            for y in range(0, cols):
                if imgArray\[x\]\[y\].shape\[:2\] == imgArray\[0\]\[0\].shape \[:2\]:
                    imgArray\[x\]\[y\] = cv2.resize(imgArray\[x\]\[y\], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
                else:
                    imgArray\[x\]\[y\] = cv2.resize(imgArray\[x\]\[y\], (imgArray\[0\]\[0\].shape\[1\], imgArray\[0\]\[0\].shape\[0\]), None, scale, scale)
                if len(imgArray\[x\]\[y\].shape) == 2: imgArray\[x\]\[y\]= cv2.cvtColor( imgArray\[x\]\[y\], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        imageBlank = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
        hor = \[imageBlank\]*rows
        hor_con = \[imageBlank\]*rows
        for x in range(0, rows):
            hor\[x\] = np.hstack(imgArray\[x\])
        ver = np.vstack(hor)
    else:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            if imgArray\[x\].shape\[:2\] == imgArray\[0\].shape\[:2\]:
                imgArray\[x\] = cv2.resize(imgArray\[x\], (0, 0), None, scale, scale)
            else:
                imgArray\[x\] = cv2.resize(imgArray\[x\], (imgArray\[0\].shape\[1\], imgArray\[0\].shape\[0\]), None,scale, scale)
            if len(imgArray\[x\].shape) == 2: imgArray\[x\] = cv2.cvtColor(imgArray\[x\], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hor= np.hstack(imgArray)
        ver = hor
    return ver

def getContours(img):
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        print(area)
        if area>100:
            cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
            peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            #print(peri)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*peri,True)
            print(len(approx))
            objCor = len(approx)
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)

            if objCor == 3: objectType = "Tri"
            else:objectType = "None"

            cv2.rectangle(imgContour,(x,y,),(x+w,y+h),(0,250,5),2)
            cv2.putText(imgContour,objectType,
                        (x+(w/2)-10,y+(h/2)-10, cv2.QT_FONT_LIGHT,0.7,
                         (0,0,0),2)


img = cv2.imread('Recources/shapesDif.png', 0)
imgContour = img.copy()
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray,(7,7),1)
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgBlur,50,50)
imgBlank = np.zeros_like(img)
getContours(imgCanny)

imgStack = stackImages(1.5,(\[img,imgGray, imgBlur\],
                            \[imgCanny,imgContour, imgBlank\]))

cv2.imshow("Stack", imgStack)

cv2.waitKey(0)**][1]
```

**Please don't read what I'm typing right now. It just says that I need more human words so I need to type jibberish so that it will let me ask this question.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7VBZ.png

Comment: You have a problem with the backslashes and the `[0]` you're trying to use, have a look for example at row 3.

Once I put the functions in a comment, it works. So also fix all the ` \[0]\ ` in your code as it is not proper syntax.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses in the line before.